# While restore document from DB to app server, get error Allowed memory size of xxxxxxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate xxxxx bytes)

Tags: php, laravel, storage, memory-limit, adsapi-php.ini

hi i want to restore the documents that i save in the database with base64 format and copy into `laravel` `storage` file folder. this is because my server get a crash.

so here is my code to restore the document from database table into folder in application server. every user have uniq id (id_pra) and i used that id as a folder name in `/public/storage/uploads/file/USERFILEID/`

```html
 $makedir = User::where('role','9')->get();
        foreach ($makedir as $mkdir){
            $path = public_path().'/storage/uploads/file/'.$mkdir->id_pra;

            $file_user = Document::get();

            if(!(file_exists($path))){
                File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);
                foreach($file_user as $file_doc){
                    if($mkdir->id_pra == $file_doc->id_praapplication){
                        $image = $file_doc->base64; 
                        $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
                        $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
                        $imageName = str_random(10).'.'.'png';
                        $new_path = public_path().'/storage/uploads/file/'.$mkdir->id_pra;
                        file_put_contents($new_path.'/'.$file_doc->upload, base64_decode($image));
                    }
                }
            }
```

i try in local, everything is work, but in production i got this error

**PHP Fatal error:  `Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7743517 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 333 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException  : Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7743517 bytes)`**

i have already change the `memory_limit` in `php.ini`  from `124M` to `2048M` , but still get the same error. i wanna try to change into -1, but the IT security did'nt allow that. anyone know what is the other solution?

i used redhat and php 7.4, and `laravel`

Comment: make sure you incease the limit of `php_fpm` not `php_cli`

Comment: for redhat the location is in /etc/php.ini right?

Comment: try this to find  the location `ssh user@ip
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"`

Comment: the location is correct, i already change the memroy_limit on that file config, but still get error

Comment: @InskoMalaysia did you restart apache and php-fpm

Comment: yes, already restart, i change to 4096M, still get error  Allowed memory size of xxxxx

Comment: fyi, the total size of file lessmore 5GB, i try to query by taking the first 10 file ->take(10), still get same error